# Getting error while creating controller in laravel though cmd. make:controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-8.1

I am trying to create controller through make controller command, but getting this error

In ClassLoader.php line 571:

include(C:\Users\hp\OneDrive - \Documents\GitHub\vehicle_tracking\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illum
inate/Contracts/Broadcasting/HasBroadcastChannel.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: have you try composer install/composer update/composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[v4.9.0, ..., v4.13.3] require maatwebsite/excel ^3.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.0.0-alpha, ..., 3.1.x-dev].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].

Comment: continue...   - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.23.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.23.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.23.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.23.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

Comment: continue...
   
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.0.0-alpha, ..., 3.0.0] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.0.1, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons ^4.9 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons[v4.9.0, ..., v4.13.3].

Comment: continue.....


To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Comment: end or error ==============================//

Comment: how about composer dump-autoload?

Comment: > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Model.php line 26:

  Interface "Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\HasBroadcastChannel" not found

Comment: It seems you modified your composer with packages that are not compatible. I will look for yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons and phpexcel compatibility. It seem that you have incompatible versions of this two packages. It is possible? BTW, you are running PHP 8.1 But some dependencies are locked at 7.x . So look for both conditions php 8.x and packages versions requeriments. Good Luck.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72656088/edit) and share the file contents of your `composer.json` file.